# How to have 3 duplicated EnvironmentObject but it can only take one per type

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var predictService1: PredictService = PredictService()
    @StateObject var predictService2: PredictService = PredictService()
    @StateObject var predictService3: PredictService = PredictService()
}
```

These are duplicated because there actually are duplicated 3 of the same views that have separate states.

I can pass these all the way down the view hierarchy. But I would rather just use environmentObject like this

```
struct MyAPP: App {
    @StateObject var predictService1: PredictService = PredictService()
        @StateObject var predictService2: PredictService = PredictService()
        @StateObject var predictService3: PredictService = PredictService()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(predictService1)
                .environmentObject(predictService2)
                .environmentObject(predictService3)    //these dont work because its only 1 of each type
        }
    }
}
```

whats the right design?

Comment: If the reason you need three services is that you have 3 views and each depends on one, why don't you create the `StateObject` in each of these views?

Comment: If it is a service and they are used by 3 different view why not make them structs and maybe even custom property wrappers.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez parent view also needs to observe

Comment: Unless the plan is to replace the environment object for some sub-hierarchies of views, environment objects are, basically, global variables. You could make it explicit by creating either global variables or, as I prefer to do, by creating "shared" instances like in this example: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/04af4655082ef1a48c20dc419f42eea8

No need to pass them using the "environment".

Comment: I can’t make a good recommendation without more information about your app, but this seems like bad architecture to me.

Comment: @Baglan wow I didn't know you can do that, can you post it as an answer and I can accept. When should we use globals, when should we use @EnvironmentObjects?

Comment: Another alternative depending on your requirements is to use a _function_  or a `Reader Monad` replacing your `PredictService` and use it in some environment _value_. With a Reader you can separate _service_ and the _configuration_ of that service, where the configuration can be set in a different environment value as well.

Comment: `@StateObject` is for state (it's in the name) not for service. Try `EnvironmentKey` like how `managedObjectContext` works.

Comment: @erotsppa use of globals is considered to be "in poor taste" by people prone to, um, "academic thinking" (and their concerns are well founded, you can read up on them online). While not a thing to utilize everywhere, it makes sense for things like data stores that need to be accessed from different places in the app. Environment is a limited clever way to pass globals through the view hierarchy. Environment hides complexity and provides some additional functionality. It works for most cases, just, it appears, not in yours, at least, not elegantly (which is it's main advantage).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's my take on your quandary:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class PredictService: ObservableObject {
  // ...
  
  // Shared instances
  
  static let service1 = PredictService()
  static let service2 = PredictService()
  static let service3 = PredictService()
}

struct SampleView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var service = PredictService.service1
  
  // ...
}
```

There are fundamental problems you (probably) need to solve:

1. Updates to the `PredictService` instances should be able to trigger UI changes in some *Views*;
2. `PredictService` instances should be retained as long as the app is running;
3. Different instances of the `PredictService` should be available to different Views in different places of the *View* hierarchy.

Your code solves these issues by:

1. Declaring the `PredictService` to be an `ObservableObject`;
2. Storing created instances as `@StateObject`;
3. Passing them down the hierarchy through the *environment*;
4. Exposing instances through the use of the `@EnvironmentObject`.

Which is a reasonable approach except that the environment seems not to  have been designed for this particular case. Hence, I suggest you do things ever so slightly differently:

1. `ObservableObject` is still needed;
2. Store instances as global variables, initializing them as static members of the `PredictService` class for convenience and readability;
3. Just use them in *Views*, no need for the *environment*;
4. Exposing them to *Views* through the `@ObservedObject`.

Note: this solution is not significantly different from what you already had, but it avoids the use of the *enviroment*. *Environment* is, essentially, a way to pass global variables through the *View* hierarchy, so, this solution is not very different from the perspective of the use of global variables if there are concerns about that aspect.